# Javascript/jQuery - How do I obtain name of the class of clicked element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I googled and googled and I concluded that it's very hard to get answer on my own.

I am trying to use jquery or JavaScript to get a property of clicked element. I can use "this.hash" for example - it returns hash value I presume.

Now I would like to get name of the class of clicked element. 
Is it even possible? How? And where would I find this kind of information?

- jQuery documentation? - All I can find is methods and plugins, no properties.. if its there - please provide me with link.
- JavaScript documentation? - is there even one comprehensive one? again please a link.
- DOM documentation? - the one on W3C or where (link appreciated).

And what is `this.hash`? - DOM JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In jQuery, if you attach a `click` event to all `<div>` tags (for example), you can get it's class like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/wpNST/

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var theClass = this.className;  // "this" is the element clicked
    alert( theClass );
});
```

This uses [jQuery's `.click(fn)` method](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to assign the handler, but access the `className` property directly from the DOM element that was clicked, which is represented by `this`.

There are jQuery methods that do this as well, [like `.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/wpNST/1/

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var theClass = $(this).attr('class');
    alert( theClass );
});
```

Here I wrapped the DOM element with a jQuery object so that it can use the methods made available by jQuery. [The `.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) here gets the class that was set.

Answer (score 11):

This example will work on every element in the page. I'd recommend using `console.log(event)` and poking around at what it dumps into your console with Firebug/Developer tools.

### jQuery

```
​$(window).click(function(e) {
    console.log(e); // then e.srcElement.className has the class
});​​​​
```

### Javascript

```
window.onclick = function(e) {
    console.log(e); // then e.srcElement.className has the class
}​
```

### Try it out

http://jsfiddle.net/M2Wvp/

**Edit**
For clarification, you don't have to log console for the `e.srcElement.className` to have the class, hopefully that doesn't confuse anyone. It's meant to show that within the function, that will have the class name.

Comment: isn't `srcElement` only available in IE and `target` for other brwosers? ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301643/how-can-i-make-event-srcelement-work-in-firefox-and-what-does-it-mean#answer-5301667))  is there another alternative that combines both keywords?

Comment: Your source has `var target = event.target || event.srcElement;`  I believe that should work.

Answer (score 8):

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    var clickElement = e.target;  // get the dom element clicked.
    var elementClassName = e.target.className;  // get the classname of the element clicked
});
```

this supports on clicking anywhere of the page. if the element you clicked doesn't have a class name, it will return null or empty string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use element.className.split(/\s+/); to get you an array of class names, remember elements can have more than one class.

Then you can iterate all of them and find the one you want.

```
window.onclick = function(e) {
    var classList = e.srcElement.className.split(/\s+/);
    for (i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
       if (classList[i] === 'someClass') {
         //do something
       }
    }
}
```

jQuery does not really help you here but if you must

```
$(document).click(function(){
    var classList =$(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    $.each( classList, function(index, item){
        if (item==='someClass') {
           //do something
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#ele').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

And here are all of the attribute functions.

http://api.jquery.com/category/attributes/

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do this without coding. Just open the console of your browser (f12?) and go to element you want. After that, hover or click the item you want to track.

Every change done on the DOM will be for a few seconds marked (or lightened) as another color on the console. (Watch the screen capture)

On the example, each time I hover a "colorItem", the 'div' parent and the "colorItem" class appears lightened. So in this case the clicked class will be 'swiper-model-watch' or 'swiper-container' (class of the lightened div)

[image: obtain name class clicked]