# window.event.srcElement is null in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

What is the work-around to handle `window.event.srcElement` in Windows 8 and IE10?

Answer (score 4):

The official event object property to get the source element is [`event.target`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Since IE9, Microsoft is moving closer and closer to the official web standards.

Kind of related: [How can I make event.srcElement work in Firefox and what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5301643/218196)

Comment: Or to be more precise and support also older browsers:
var target = event.target || event.srcElement