# AngularJS / jQuery "parent()" selects different element in FF than in Chrome and Safari, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, angularjs, firefox

I've found a bizarre quirk in AngularJS/Firefox where the selectors use grab different elements. I've put it in a Plunker to demonstrate it's effect:

http://plnkr.co/edit/H7stCpQE59i0aUlQ865j?p=preview

Open it in Chrome and click the button. You're actually selecting a hidden `<input>` element, then Angular passes it's event/parent along, grabs the parent `<button>` and adds the class `.active` to it, like so:

```
$scope.selectTag = function($event){
        var elem = angular.element($event.srcElement).parent();
        if(elem.hasClass('active')){
            elem.removeClass( "active" );
        }else{
            elem.addClass('active');
        }   
    }
```

In Firefox, though, it selects the `<input>` element and adds `.active` to that rather than the `<button>` that is its parent.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Probably you should use `target` instead of `srcElement` like `var elem = angular.element($event.target).parent();`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301643/how-can-i-make-event-srcelement-work-in-firefox-and-what-does-it-mean for a description of $event.srcElement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the comment by Arun P Johny, use `$event.target` rather than `srcElement`. But, you shouldn't be manipulating the DOM like that when using Angular JS. Instead, you could do this with `ng-class`.

```
<label class="btn btn-default" ng-class="foo">
  <input class="" ng-click="foo=(foo==='active') ? '' : 'active'" type="checkbox" />
    Button Text
</label>
```

Comment: I'll mark this correct as it was first / answered the main issue. Cheers mate!

Comment: @Jascination Nice, thanks! For anyone that sees this, do also see charlietfl's answer!

Answer (score 3):

No need for using jQuery. Just use `ng-class`. Following requires zero code in controller to accomplish what your code will end up doing. Also controllers shouldn't have any DOM manipulation code in them

```
<label class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{active:btn_active}" >
  <input class="" ng-click="btn_active=!btn_active" type="checkbox" />
    Button Text
</label>
```

Learn to look for angular approaches first before using jQuery methodology!

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/WJlXOjiPviWEPQtzar42?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Ah dangit. I think yours is better. Same idea :)