# TypeError in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox

This is really confusing me.  Everything runs smooth in Chrome and Safari, but I get an error in Firefox:

```
TypeError: currentButton is undefined
```

It lists the "index - currentButton" line as the source of the error. I'd love to know what I did wrong here!  Hopefully this is enough code to track down the problem:

```
document.getElementById('buttons').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

var currentButton = e.srcElement,
    index = currentButton.getAttribute('data-index');
```

Comment: so... what's e.srcElement?  have you tried logging that to the console?

Comment: Do some searching: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5301667/712558

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make event.srcElement work in Firefox and what does it mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301643/how-can-i-make-event-srcelement-work-in-firefox-and-what-does-it-mean)

Comment: @danronmoon This one was tricky—you have to admit.

Comment: @Luxelin 1:  Reason that currentButton is undefined which means e.srcElement is undefined.  2:  type in srcElement into google. 3: profit.

Comment: @danronmoon He should've just defaulted to `event.target` anyway. tl;dr: just use `event.target`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
document.getElementById('buttons').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    var currentButton = e.target || e.srcElement,
            index = currentButton.getAttribute('data-index');
```