# Id from anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is this possible with php and javascript? 
Can I echo my anchor tag ID and retrieve it with jquery onclick event?
Echo " a href = 'example.con' id=' ".$row['userid']."' example /a"; now in jquery/javascript I say something like onclick of the anchor tag I get the id of whatever the row is. If not can someone give me another solution.

Comment: Can you try rephrasing that so that a person who isn't you might be able to understand it?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
$('#myLinkId').click(function() {
    var linkId;
    linkId = $(this).prop('id');
    alert(linkId);
});
```

This code: `.prop('id');` is specifically what gets the link's ID.

Comment: @Satpal so it does! I wasn't even aware of that. Satpal's solution shoudl have better performance. Although, the jQuery way can have its uses too, for example, looping through a string list of properties.

Comment: Your method is correct. I have just suggested that you can also use it.

Answer (score 0):

Non jQuery alternative:

```
function getId(e){
    //IE e.srcElement.href);
    //Other e.target.href);
    alert(e.srcElement.id);
}
```

Add the onclick="getId(event)" to your anchor.

For crossbrowser implementation you can see this question:

[How can I make event.srcElement work in Firefox and what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301643/how-can-i-make-event-srcelement-work-in-firefox-and-what-does-it-mean)