# Angular2 get clicked element id

Tags: angular

I have such click event

```
 <button (click)="toggle($event)" class="someclass" id="btn1"></button>
 <button (click)="toggle($event)" class="someclass" id="btn2"></button>
```

I am catching the event in my function input param and want to find out what exactly button was clicked.

```
toggle(event) {

}
```

but `event` does not have an `id` property.

```
altKey: false
bubbles: true
button: 0
buttons: 0
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: true
clientX: 1198
clientY: 29
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: button#hdrbtn_notificaton.mdl-button.mdl-js-button.mdl-js-ripple-effect.mdl-button--icon
defaultPrevented: false
detail: 1
eventPhase: 3
fromElement: null
isTrusted: true
isTrusted: true
layerX: -566
layerY: 5
metaKey: false
movementX: 0
movementY: 0
offsetX: 22
offsetY: 13
pageX: 1198
pageY: 29
path: Array[13]
relatedTarget: null
returnValue: true
screenX: 1797
screenY: 148
shiftKey: false
sourceCapabilities: InputDeviceCapabilities
srcElement: span.mdl-button__ripple-container
target: span.mdl-button__ripple-container
timeStamp: 1458032708743
toElement: span.mdl-button__ripple-container
type: "click"
view: Window
webkitMovementX: 0
webkitMovementY: 0
which: 1
x: 1198
y: 29
```

How can I find an `id`?

UPDATE:
**Plunkers are all good** but in my case I have locally:

`event.srcElement.attributes.id` - undefined
`event.currentTarget.id` - has the value

I am using chrome latest Version 49.0.2623.87 m

Could it be `Material Design Lite` thing? because I am using it.

[image]

Comment: what you want to do with `id` ?

Comment: I have two buttons firing same click function. So I need to find out which one was clicked

Comment: simply pass the static/dynamic `id` along with perameters.

Comment: why it is so hard to get an `id`?

Comment: Seems to be a `button` issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button

Comment: just found that in `event.currentTarget.id`

Comment: i have post the answer where you can get the `id` simply. or via `event.srcElement.attributes.id`

Comment: in my case `event.srcElement.attributes.id` is `undefined`

Comment: not at all i am using chrome. see my plnkr its working fine.

Comment: Planker is OK but locally it is not giving the id this way.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

If you want to have access to the `id` attribute of the button you can leverage the `srcElement` property of the event:

```ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="onClick($event)" id="test">Click</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  onClick(event) {
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
    var idAttr = target.attributes.id;
    var value = idAttr.nodeValue;
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/QGdou4?p=preview.

See this question:

- [How can I make event.srcElement work in Firefox and what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301643/how-can-i-make-event-srcelement-work-in-firefox-and-what-does-it-mean)

Comment: `event.srcElement.attributes.id` is undefined do not know why... but I found an `id` in `event.currentTarget.id`

Comment: Really? Did you see my plunkr? It's what I use and it's not undefined... In my case (Chrome), `currentTarget` is undefined :-( Which browser do you use?

Comment: In fact, it's either srcElement or target according browsers. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301643/how-can-i-make-event-srcelement-work-in-firefox-and-what-does-it-mean

Comment: the Planker is OK but in my particular case I am not getting id locally from `event.srcElement.attributes.id`

Comment: `event.target` should work... I updated my answer. What is your particular case? ;-)

Comment: I am using `Material Design Lite` may be it is screwing the `event.srcElement.attributes.id` because it is wasn't being build for using with Angular2 for my understanding so may be that is a reason why `event.srcElement.attributes.id` is not working.

Comment: Chrome: `angular2.dev.js:23597 TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined`

Comment: I think it could be simplified just to this `var target = event.srcElement.attributes.id || event.currentTarget.id;`. The above error I've got in `var value = idAttr.nodeValue;`

Comment: The problem is if `event.srcElement` is undefined, you will have an error when trying to access the `attributes` property...

Comment: How do you initialize the `idAttr` variable?

Comment: I endup of using this `var target = event.srcElement.attributes.id || event.currentTarget.id;`

Comment: @sreginogemoh Try to add id as the second string attribute to onClick function. Works for me!

Comment: The expression "event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget" is mixing different things. event.target is the element that fired the event, event.currentTarget is the element on which the listener is registered. In many cases, they are different elements.

Comment: @sreginogemoh : Thanks a lot,.. this worked it out.. ng 7.2

Comment: depending on your use case, you may want to change the order of: `event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget`

Answer (score 49):

For TypeScript users:

```
    toggle(event: Event): void {
        let elementId: string = (event.target as Element).id;
        // do something with the id... 
    }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion.However it can be   
 ``const elementId: string = (event.target as Element).id;``

Comment: that returns blank for me. Not null or undefined but blank

Comment: Thanks.  I was so confused why I couldn't check a property of target, or srcTarget, directly when I could see them all in the console.   Cast as Element, duh.

Comment: This should definitely be the top answer.

Comment: @DarrenStreet how did you solve it? it is blank for me too

Comment: @Snk Sorry mate, forgotten, 2 years is a long time in coding land. I would have been using a Mat Button so returned a specific mat button event type I recon. Or maybe Viewchild to get a ref to the button.

Comment: @DarrenStreet no prob mate, I'm using primeng so Mat won't work, will try with ViewChild. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Finally found the simplest way:

```
<button (click)="toggle($event)" class="someclass" id="btn1"></button>
<button (click)="toggle($event)" class="someclass" id="btn2"></button>

toggle(event) {
   console.log(event.target.id); 
}
```

Comment: This might be a tricky: if your button has some HTML content, like `<button ...><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>` and you actually click on that `i` element, which is FontAwasome component, then the event.target is not a `button` but the `i` element.

Comment: To get the `button` element use `event.target.closest('button')`.

Answer (score 20):

You could just pass a static value (or a variable from `*ngFor` or whatever)

```ts
<button (click)="toggle(1)" class="someclass">
<button (click)="toggle(2)" class="someclass">
```

Comment: do you think is it better to avoid of using an `id` in such case?

Comment: If the only purpose is to pass it as event parameter then I wouldn't use an id.

Comment: Instead of using `id` just pick an index from an array or so. It's often surprising that we overlook the most straight-forward solutions so frequently.

Answer (score 12):

There is no need to pass the entire event (unless you need other aspects of the event than you have stated). In fact, it is not recommended. You can pass the element reference with just a little modification.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button #btn1 (click)="toggle(btn1)" class="someclass" id="btn1">Button 1</button>
    <button #btn2 (click)="toggle(btn2)" class="someclass" id="btn2">Button 2</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  buttonValue: string;

  toggle(button) {
    this.buttonValue = button.id;
  }

}
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckcghk)

Technically, you don't need to find the button that was clicked, because you have passed the actual element.

[Angular guidance](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#passing-event-is-a-dubious-practice)

Comment: This should be the correct answer as referred by @Greg's Link to the Angular guidance!

Answer (score 4):

**When your `HTMLElement` doesn't have an `id`, `name` or `class` to call,**

then use

```
<input type="text" (click)="selectedInput($event)">

selectedInput(event: MouseEvent) {
   log(event.srcElement) // HTMInputLElement
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use its **interface** `HTMLButtonElement` that inherits from its parent `HTMLElement` !

This way you will be able to have **auto-completion**...

```
<button (click)="toggle($event)" class="someclass otherClass" id="btn1"></button>

toggle(event: MouseEvent) {
    const button = event.target as HTMLButtonElement;
    console.log(button.id);
    console.log(button.className);
 }
```

[To see all list of HTMLElement from the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) documentation](https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/html2/HTMLElement.html)

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xydjzr)

Answer (score 2):

do like this simply: (as said in comment here is with example with two methods)

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app', 
    template: `
      <button (click)="checkEvent($event,'a')" id="abc" class="def">Display Toastr</button>
      <button (click)="checkEvent($event,'b')" id="abc1" class="def1">Display Toastr1</button>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  checkEvent(event, id){
    console.log(event, id, event.srcElement.attributes.id);
  }
}
```

demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/5kJaj9D13srJxmod213r?p=preview

Comment: `event.srcElement.attributes.id` is undefined in my case do not know why... but I found an `id` in `event.currentTarget.id`

Comment: just checkout in the Object of `event` fired where you can see `id`

Comment: @sreginogemoth you can also check:
`event.target.id`
it can also have the id value

Answer (score 2):

For nested html, use `closest`

```
<button (click)="toggle($event)" class="someclass" id="btn1">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
</button>

toggle(event) {
   (event.target.closest('button') as Element).id; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the value of an attribute by its name, enabling you to get the value of a custom attribute such as an attribute from a Directive:

```
<button (click)="toggle($event)" id="btn1" myCustomAttribute="somevalue"></button>


toggle( event: Event ) {
  const eventTarget: Element = event.target as Element;
  const elementId: string = eventTarget.id;
  const attribVal: string = eventTarget.attributes['myCustomAttribute'].nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have access to the `id` attribute of the button in angular 6 follow this code

```
`@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="clicked($event)" id="myId">Click Me</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  clicked(event) {
    const target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
    const idAttr = target.attributes.id;
    const value = idAttr.nodeValue;
  }
}`
```

your `id` in the value,

the value of `value` is `myId`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use event.path like below

Html:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let r of rows" id="{{r}}">
        <td>
            <span>
                <button (click)="deleteRow($event)" type="button" 
                class="btn-close"></button> 
            </span>   
        </td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

ts:

```
deleteRow(evemt:any){

this.rows.pop()
console.log(evemt.path[3].id);
}
```

in evemt.path[3].id  3 is which parent's you want to access start from 1 is immediate parent

Answer (score 0):

all the answeres here leads to an issue,
the `$event` here not always refers to the button itself, and may refer to another element

here is an example

```
<button (click)="onClick($event)">
  <mat-icon>ok</mat-icon>
  <span>Click here!</span>
</button>
```

and...

```
onClick(ev: MouseEvent){
  let target = ev.target
}
```

`ev.target` here can point to the icon or the `<span` elements rather that the button itself

one solution here is to check if the target is not a button, so your desired target here is `ev.taget.parentElement` instead of `ev.target`