# Angular2 Detect id and class

Tags: angular

Let say I have the following in angular:

```
<div class="dwiws" id="som" (click)="someFunction()">
      some content                                
</div>
```

Then in `.ts`, I have the following:

```
  someFunction(){
       //Want to detect the class and id of the div i clicked.
  };
```

I want to detect the id and class of the div that the click function lies.

How do I do it?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006894/angular2-get-clicked-element-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***srcElement*** property and get that info.

```
<button (click)="someFunction($event)" id="myid" 
     class="myclass">Click</button>


  someFunction(event) {
      console.log(event);
      console.log(event.srcElement.attributes.id);
      console.log(event.srcElement.attributes.class);
  }
```