# Radio input with surrounded by anchor tag doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, checkbox, radio-button

I writing an app in AngularJS2, and I have a simple navigation bar on the top. The user is supposed to click on navigation and page jump to sections.
Navigation has inline anchor tags with input radio buttons in them.

```
<label for="yp">
     <a href="test.com" target="_blank"><input type="radio" id="yp">This is a radio bitton</a>
</label>
```

The problem is sometimes anchor tag works, and radio input doesn't, and sometimes radio input works and the anchor doesn't.

How can I resolve it preferably without JS/AngularJS2?

Comment: Rather than surrounding your radio button with an anchor tag, you could call a function which will perform the jumping between sections when a radio button is selected (`onclick`).

Comment: @how do I dot in angular 2?

Comment: This should help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006894/angular2-get-clicked-element-id

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will confuse Angular, because when you click, angular does not know if you clicked button or a tag or both.

Try something like this:

```
    <input type="radio" id="yp">
    <a href="test.com" target="_blank">This is a radio bitton</a>
```

You may also want add some CSS to align input and a tags as you want.