# Why does not work function in Angular 2 Typescript is called from template?

Tags: angular

I have a following tag:

```
<tag-input hideForm="true" [onRemoving]="onRemoving"></tag-input>
```

Where `[onRemoving]="onRemoving"` is function is called by attempts to delete value.

It looks like:

```
public onRemoving(tag: any): Observable<any> {

    let del = '';

    this.translate.get('confirmation_text').subscribe((res: string) => {
      del = res['confirmation_text'];
    });
}
```

Problem is in this code:

`this.translate.get('confirmation_text').subscribe()...`

I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

I think cause is in area of visibility of `this` context

Constructor:

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
}
```

Comment: Can you add your constructor, where the dependency injection should happen?

Comment: Yes, look again

Comment: I think I can not get access to global `this` of class, it works only with local this of  `tag-input`;

Comment: show the `this.translate.get`

Comment: ` this.translate.get('confirmation_text').subscribe((res: string) => {
      del = res['confirmation_text'];
    });`

Comment: I think I need this: `public onRemoving(tag: any, th?:this): Observable<any> {}`

Comment: @Jessie have you imported TranslateService ?

Comment: Exactly, it works in another method

Comment: Again, I think problem is in area of visibility

Comment: No. it should work. Check that  TranslateService has @Injectable() annotation

Comment: Yes, it has ` @Injectable()`

Comment: Function is called from template context: `[onRemoving]="onRemoving"`.

Comment: try to  change [onRemoving] to (onRemoving)

Comment: No, does not work

Comment: Write in constructor the following `this.onRemoving = this.onRemoving.bind(this)`

Comment: Yes, it works, post this as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `[onRemoving]="onRemoving"` to `(onRemoving)="onRemoving($event)"`

It might be useful [Angular2, ng2-tag-input prevent duplicate value on editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46979322/angular2-ng2-tag-input-prevent-duplicate-value-on-editable)

Comment: And how to pass parameter to `"onRemoving()"`?

Comment: It does not work, it removes tags without confirmation in this case

Comment: May be `(onRemoving)="onRemoving($event)"`?

Comment: yes, you can use $event as param if you want to pass browser's event object

Comment: I tried,  
It does not work, it removes tags without confirmation in this case

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006894/angular2-get-clicked-element-id

Comment: `(onRemoving)="onRemoving($event)"`

Comment: And component is: `public onRemoving(tag: any): Observable<any> {}`