# A click event is being triggered on all the inputs instead of only the one which was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angular, input

1. **When I click on a single input, all inputs are triggered.**
2. **I just want the input I clicked to be triggered**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyR17.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1D80B.png)

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of TransferCardWeb">
                            <td>{{item.PartiNo}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.SeriNo}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.StokKodu}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.StokAdi}}</td>
                            <td>
                          <tr *ngIf="!visible"  (click)="itemQuantityOnClick()"> {{item.Quantity}}
```

> (click)="itemQuantityOnClick() : What should I write inside this method?

```
                          </tr>

                          <tr *ngIf="visible">
                            <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="item.NewQuantity" min="0" (keydown)="itemQuantityChangeKey($event,item)"
                              style="width:100%; height:100%;">
                          </tr>
```

> Typescript

```
itemQuantityOnClick()
  {       
    this.visible = true;
          }
```

Comment: this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006894/angular2-get-clicked-element-id

Comment: I have only one input.It is filled in javascript according to the incoming values and multiplies @TobiasS.

Comment: You should asign an Id to each input. Change the ngFor to ```*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"``` so you have ```i```` to use as id of the ```input```. Then you can retrieve the id of the clicked input inside ```itemQuantityOnClick()```.

Comment: Go to your **item** `interface` and add a variable to respond to your condition.

In your template, inside the `*ngFor directive` pass the object to the function.

Comment: Yess , good plan bro.Thanks man.I will do try @TobiasS.