# show button class name on click using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i have a requirement where i need to show the class name of button which has been clicked using `java script`. there are many buttons with different class names.Any suggestion?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
var container = document.getElementById(id);
alert (container);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<button class="A" id="A" onclick="myFunction()">A</button>
<button class="B" id="B" onclick="myFunction()">B</button>
<button class="C" id="C" onclick="myFunction()">C</button>
<button class="D" id="D" onclick="myFunction()">D</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this is what you are looking for ?

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3774720/1172872

Comment: You have getElementById , yet no **ID** in your _buttons_.

Comment: sorry i am putting it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [className](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20001113/html.html#ID-95362176) [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className) of the [dom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element) to get the class name.

```
<button class="A" onclick="myFunction(this)">A</button>
<button class="B" onclick="myFunction(this)">B</button>
<button class="C" onclick="myFunction(this)">C</button>
<button class="D" onclick="myFunction(this)">D</button>

function myFunction(el) {
    alert (el.className);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Fhh63/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Is this is what you are looking for ?

```
 window.onclick = function(e) {
     console.log(e); // then e.srcElement.className has the class
 }​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M2Wvp/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3774720/1172872

Answer (score 1):

try like

```
<button id="A" class="b" onclick="myFunction(this)">A</button>
```

and to access the classname

```
function myFunction(el)
{
    console.log(el.className);
}
```

here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wfgdj/)