# 10x10 table and store X/Y of cell selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was hoping to somehow implement a 10x10 table onto my webpage where you select a cell and then store the X and Y value of the cell clicked but I'm really not sure on how to store the values, or to make the cell interactive.

My end goal is pretty much something like this: http://materdeimath.pbworks.com/f/GraphPaper20x20AxesUnits.bmp
Where I can store the X/Y values of the clicked cell, is this possible?

If any of you guys have any idea how I would accomplish this I would really appreciate the help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me I would start with this way but there are other ways to get you started. Here are my steps:

1. Bootstrap responsive grid system [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp). Make each grid an individual id and class e.g. id="x1y1","x2y1","x3y1",class="col-interactive" something like chess grid if you familiar with that. The reason for a separate class is to identify from the common class used by plugins.
2. Using jQuery to get the class/name/id of the grid clicked. You may find reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774699/javascript-jquery-how-do-i-obtain-name-of-the-class-of-clicked-element).
3. Finally using ajax to call your server side (e.g. PHP) and database (e.g. MySQL) validation. Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707648/using-jquery-ajax-to-retrieve-data-from-mysql).